# Blender to Android studio

Tags: game-engine

i tried making a game with blender engine and used 3d modules from blender 3d can i import it to android studio? since blender doesn't support Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I think there has been some work done to get blender running on an android device, I wouldn't recommend trying at this stage.

You can export your 3D models and open them in an Android application, though using Android studio would mean programming the game yourself.

I would recommend using an external game engine, such as [godot](https://godotengine.org/) or [unity](https://unity3d.com/) to create an android game, both of these can use the models you create in blender.

Comment: ok thanks i will create in blender and export to unity